# Plot a Morris chart line in RUBY ON RAILS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, morris.js

i'm using  the MORRIS JS to plot a chart line in my Ruby On Rails Project

I retreive Data from my Database : MYSQL and want to plot it in Morris JS CHART

I return an Array of data from Database.
My Problem: is that the MORRIS JS , just plot the first row of my array , i don't know dose not plot all the data retreived from MYSQL DATABASE.

Please, i need help

So this my Code

My controller

```
     require 'json'

    @get_data =  CttGueHydro2Aae.where("Date_YMDHMS  >= '2017-05-10 16:10:12'")
    #@get_data  = CttGueHydro2Aae.all

    @chart_data = Array.new
    obj = {}

    obj["time"] = " "
    obj["value"] = " "

    @get_data.each do |data|
        obj["time"] = data.Date_YMDHMS
        obj["value"] = data.AAE_8062
        @chart_data.push(obj)
    end
     #Json Conversion
    @chart_data = @chart_data.to_json



  end
```

View>Index.html.erb

```html
<div id="myfirstchart" style="height: 250px;"></div>





<script type="text/javascript">


new Morris.Line({
  // ID of the element in which to draw the chart.
  element: 'myfirstchart',
  // Chart data records -- each entry in this array corresponds to a point on
  // the chart.
  data: <%= @chart_data.html_safe %>,
  // The name of the data record attribute that contains x-values.
  xkey: 'time',
  // A list of names of data record attributes that contain y-values.
  ykeys: ['value'],
  // Labels for the ykeys -- will be displayed when you hover over the
  // chart.
  labels: ['Value']
});


</script>
```

So, when i run the Server from command line : rails s 
Just the Morris plot the first value of my array

**PLOT IN MY BROWSER :**

[image]

from the DEBEGUER of MY BROWSER i get this : **Inspector of my code in the browser :**

[image]

All

Comment: Hi, you're using the same image.

Comment: hi jmj , i just changed the second image

Comment: please  i nedd help